# Using OpenAI API from Firebase Cloud Functions in flutter app

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

**Updated**

I can't figure out how to make this work.

This is my cloud function in Javascript. I'm trying a simple code to see if the connection works (other cloud functions not using the openai package do work fine).

The function does work on GCP when I test it, but won't connect to my flutter function for some reason:

error:

`flutter: Error calling Firebase Function: internal Response is missing data field.`

Cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();

exports.openAiResponse2 = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const apiKey = 'sk-';
  cors(request, response, async () => {
    try {
      const apiResponse = await axios.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        {
          model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
          messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Say this is a test!' }],
          temperature: 0.7,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );

     // response.status(200).json({ message: 'OpenAI API connection successful.', engines: apiResponse.data });
        response.status(200).json({
              message: 'OpenAI API connection successful.',
              completion: apiResponse.data.choices[0].message.content,
            });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to OpenAI API:', error);
      response.status(500).send('Error connecting to OpenAI API');
    }
  });
});
```

Flutter:

```
Future<void> talkToMe2() async {
  try {
    HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('openAiResponse2');
    print(callable);
    final response = await callable.call();
    print('response is $response');
    print('External API response: ${response.data}');
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
    print('Error calling Firebase Function: ${e.code} ${e.message}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error calling Firebase Function: $e');
  }
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0",
    "openai": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale en-ES)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I can't seem to find a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you see in the Cloud Functions log? `console.error("Error connecting to OpenAI API:", error);` shall log the error. Also, do you deploy your Cloud Function to Firebase or you are testing with the emulator?

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I am deploying. Looks like the code didn't reach the console.error, but I placed it before and catched this:
Error connecting to OpenAI API 1: Error: Request failed with status code 400
Error connecting to OpenAI API 2: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"

Comment: It seems there is a problem to contact the openAI API... But what do you get if you put `console.log("OpenAI Response:", openAiResponse);` before `const openAiResponse = response.data.choices[0].text;` since it seems the problem is that `response.data` is undefined. Also you may change `console.error()` to `console.log()`

Comment: Error connecting to OpenAI API 2: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'openAiResponse' before initialization

Comment: OK I made a mistake in my last comment. Can you do `const response = await openai.createCompletion({...}); console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: Hey @RenaudTarnec I managed to isolate the problem, looks like the problem is that flutter is not understanding the response from the cloud function (which I changed and now it works when I test it in GCP.  I edited the code to the latest version.
Error: flutter: Error calling Firebase Function: internal Response is missing data field.

Comment: Nice to hear that you solved your problem. Instead of deleting the original content you shoudl keep it and add the new content at the bottom of your question: if other users try to understand the problem they might be puzzled without seeing the original question

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec I'll keep it in mind for the next time. I didn't solve the issue tho, only isolated it to the openai function in flutter that for some reason doesn't work well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a flutter developer but `httpsCallable` is for `onCall` not `onRequest`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd

If you look at the flutter sample, you should have something like below for https callable

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.listFruit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { //<<<-- not onRequest
  return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"]
});
```

Comment: Very good catch @loremipsum!

Comment: @XavierColomés glad to help. Do you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark and maybe upvoting?

Comment: Thank you @lorem ipsum, that works! I had response from the function "this is a test", but when I try to prompt the API I get a unknown "OpenAI API connection failed." Also I noticed that I'm using 1st gen functions, not 2gen

Comment: @XavierColomés I couldn’t tell you there, I’ve been a native iOS developer for a while now and I stumble through nodejs I am using axios with promises and “return” on then and “throw” on catch. I also make the parameters strings I don’t know if that matters. Those are the biggest differences I see with your code or mine.

Comment: Actually with a little of chatgpt help I made it work, thanks for putting me on the right direction guys!